# Python - Back to previous page and .destroy() page in one button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an output page which displays information after searching and selecting it. In the output page, I have a button that says "Back to Search", which will go back to the search window (which are two different windows). How can I make the back button go back AND close the output window at the same time?

I've tried putting both functions in one function:

```
def backandclose():
    lambda: os.system("python Search.py"))
    root.quit

root = Tk()

back_button = Button(root, text="<<Back To Search", command=backandclose)
back_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

That code seems to do nothing. 
I know if I put just:

```
command = lambda: os.system("python Search.py")
```

next to the button, it opens my Search.py window.

I want it to also **.quit()** or **.destroy()** my original window, so that when I press the back button Search.py opens and the current window closes.

Comment: *"press the back button Search.py opens and the current window closes."*: Remove the `lambda`, you have to `detache` the `python Search.py` from the `os.system` process. This leads to the `os.system` call returns at once and `.destroy()` can get called.

Comment: `root.quit` is not the same as `root.quit()`. The former does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Bryan Oakley in the comments:

> `root.quit` is not the same as `root.quit()`. The former does nothing.

However, it is probably more appropriate to your problem to make use of a `tk.Toplevel` window that you spawn when needed, and close afterwards.

Maybe something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def spawn_top():
    top = tk.Toplevel(app, bg='cyan')
    top.title('additional info')
    top.geometry('200x100')
    tk.Button(top, text='back to search', command=top.destroy).pack()

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('200x200')
app.title('search window')
tk.Button(app, text='spawn additional info', command=spawn_top).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

(I have added a `back to search` button in the spawned toplevel, but it is not entirely necessary as closing this window will automatically revert the focus to the root app.)